# How do I unset all functions in zsh?

Tags: zsh, function

I know that I can use `unset -f $FUNCTION_NAME` to unset a single function in bash / zsh, but how do I unset all functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `zsh` shell, you may *disable* all functions using

```
disable -f -m '*'
```

(literally, "disable each function whose name matches `*`").

You may then enable them again with the analogous `enable` call.

You may also use `unset` in a similar way to remove the functions completely from the current environment:

```
unset -f -m '*'
```

Comment: Is there a way to disable all functions whose names don't start with `_`, or only disable functions defined in a file? Thanks!

Comment: @TeddyC My answer uses `*` as a globbing pattern that matches all function names. You could use `disable -f -m '[!_]*'` to disable all functions that does not start with an underscore. This could not be used for disabling the functions defined in a file unless their names follow a specific pattern. If by "defined" you mean that their names are simply listed, one per line, in a file, you could use `disable -f $(<thefile)`

Comment: By "defined" I mean that what the functions do are defined in the file - what about this case then? Thanks!

Comment: @TeddyC This is quite a different problem then. You may want to ask about this in a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

The associative array [`functions`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-functions-2) contains all the defined functions (including autoloading stubs), so [`${(k)functions}`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) expands to the list of names of defined functions.

```
unset -f ${(k)functions}
```